# .hide() child elements hide with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I've got a `<div>` and there are different elements in it.

Problem is that if I trigger jQuery `.hide()`, parent `<div>` hides almost immediately (with it's background color) and other elements just hang in "the air" and disappear with slight delay, they even have delay between each other, like all the elements where in a line and couldn't hide at once.

I've messed around with CSS for several hours, transitions are same and I couldn't replicate this problem in jsFiddle.

What could be the issue?

```
<div class="map-marker-wrapper">
    <div class="map-marker-container">

        <div class="arrow-down"></div>

        <img src="' . $marker_thumbnail . '" />

        <div class="content">
            <a href="' . $marker_permalink . '">
            <h5 class="title">' . $marker_title . '</h5>
            </a>' .
            $marker_price . '  
            <div class="more-content">
                <span>' . $marker_size . ' </span>
                <span> ' . $marker_price. ' </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
removeMarkers();

//Remove map markers and marker cluster
function removeMarkers() {

    for( i = 0; i < newMarkers.length; i++ ) {

        markers[i].setMap( null );

        //Close infoboxes
        if ( markers[i].infobox.getVisible() ) {

            markers[i].infobox.hide();
        }
    }

    if ( cluster ) { 

        cluster.clearMarkers();
    }

    markers = [];
    newMarkers = [];
    bounds = [];
}
```

Comment: i suggest you include cs and js

Comment: Hiding a parent element automatically hides all its children. You must have a plugin that's causing the weird hiding that you're seeing.

Comment: you can use the `fadeOut` function in jQuery

Comment: if you change hide() to hide(1), does it work better?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes It works but same results.

Comment: @guradio Im working on it.

Comment: @Barmar  I have very few carefully selected plugins that shouldn't have anything to do with any of this.

Comment: @JohnPangilinan Thanks, I'll give it a shot if everything else fails.

Comment: Well, what you're describing is not the normal behavior of `.hide()`, so you must have something on the page that's doing this. Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: @JohnPangilinan I don't think he's asking how to make it fade slowly, he's asking why the child elements aren't hiding at the same time as the parent.

Comment: @Barmar22 oh ok, i didn't get quite well with the question. i thought he was asking for hide delay.
#Solo: which div are you trying to hide?

Comment: @JohnPangilinan This is all a content of infobox in Google Maps which is declared as variable in JS. I just call `infobox.hide()` which should be the wrapper of all this `HTML` in my question.

Comment: Have you tried `.hide(400)` or `.fadeOut()` ?

Comment: @TareqMahmood Yes, first option have same results, even with `1000` and I can't use `.fadeout()` in my current situation.

Comment: Have you tried hiding the children first then the parent?
`infobox.children().hide(); infobox.hide()`

Comment: Pls post your JS code here, which will be better helpful.

Comment: @TareqMahmood I thought this is not helping you in any way because it's pretty straight-forward JS but I'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `markers[i].infobox.hide();` to `jQuery( '.infoBox' ).hide();` eliminates the problem.

Im not sure if it has any impacts *(performance or something else)* but I guess time will tell.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

$( "div" ).hide( "slow" );

and for more reference :

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

to avoid hide parent element

example on js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t8Lnsux5/5/

```
$(".more-content").click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});

$(".content").click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```